# Periodicity in the hyperreals

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, nonstandard-analysis

Suppose we had a sequence say $K=\langle1,8,5,1,8,5,1,8,5,\ldots\rangle$ periodic on these $3$ numbers and our ultrafilter contained the odd numbers.

Then am I right in  thinking that K could be $\langle1\rangle$ or $\langle8\rangle$ or the periodic sequence $\langle1,8,1,8,1,8,\ldots\rangle$?

Also since hyperreals are sets of equivalence classes of sequences, does this mean that the sequence $\langle1\rangle$, $\langle8\rangle$, $\langle1,8,1,8,\ldots\rangle$ all belong to the same equivalence class and are therefore all equal?

Thanks.

Comment: The statement "our ultrafilter contained the odd numbers" seems unclear to me.  An ultrafilter consists of subsets of the indexes, so perhaps you are saying one of its sets is all the odd indexes?

Comment: Hardmath: Yes sorry I was meaning that it contains all the odd indexes rather than having the even indexes.

Comment: Okay, but it is hard to see the relevance to considering a sequence like $K$ of period three.  We can of course discard all the even indexes, but then the remaining entries of $K$ look like $1,5,8,1,5,8,\ldots$, so again a sequence of period three.

Comment: It was just a random example. K could also be simply just the constant sequence 1, 5, or 8 as well? And am I right in thinking they would all belong to the same equivalence class and therefore be equal (modulo the ultrafilter).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  The constant sequence of 1's will not be equivalent to the constant sequences of 5's or 8's, whatever ultrafilter is involved.  Are you familiar with the distinction between principal and non-principal ultrafilters?

Comment: Ah of course. Yes I was just being a bit silly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not distinguishing sufficiently in your notation between the sequence on the one hand and the hyperreal number generated by it (as an equivalence class), on the other, but if I understood your question correctly then yes, $K$ could be either of those things, provided there are infinitely many occurrences of "$1$" in the first case, for example. This depends on the ultrafilter.

To introduce better notation you could exploit the following convention.  A sequence $u$ is $\langle u_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ whereas its equivalence class could be denoted $[u]$ (or alternatively $[u_n]$).

Comment: Thanks. How would you suggest sufficiently distinguishing between the two?

Comment: @mattchoo one usually uses square brackets in this context to denote the equivalence class.

Comment: so the sequence would be K denoted by <1,8,5,1,8,5,..> and then the possible values that K could take on given that we have the set of odd numbers in our ultrafilter would be [1] [5] [8]

Comment: I tried to clarify as part of my answer. There is not much point in putting brackets around the usual numbers like $1,5,8$ because they are identified with their images in the hyperreals anyway.

Comment: I do use that notation you wrote above, but now im confused aren't the equivalence classes of K the constant sequences 1 5 and 8?. I know a hyperreal number is a set of equivalence classes, that depends on whats in the ultrafilter

Comment: A hyperreal number is *not* a set of equivalence classes.  A hyperreal number is *a single* equivalence class of sequences with respect to a suitable equivalence relation. The equivalence relation is defined in terms of the ultrafilter. What book are you using?

Comment: Typo on my part. So as another example say if K was the sequence <0,1,0,1,0,1,..> and our ultrafilter contained the even numbers then would the equivalence class of K by [1]?. I know that we would get the constant sequence as we would take all the even indices within K. I'm just getting confused over once we've done this what the actual equivalence class is.

Comment: @mattchoo, if the set of even integers is contained in the ultrafilter then your sequence will represent the number $1$, correct.

Comment: The equivalence class contains all sequences obtained from the one you started with by modifying it on a negligible collection of indices.  The notion of being negligible is of course determined by the ultrafilter.

Comment: Ah okay starting to become clearer. So then returning back to the original example there is just one equivalence class that contains the constant sequences 1,5 and 8. Im using the Goldblatt back, just learning about Halos and Galaxies and Shadows.

Comment: No, each constant sequence will define the corresponding real embedded inside the hyperreals.  Why would you want to collapse the real numbers? That's not nice.

Comment: Remember the hyperreals are supposed to be an extension of the reals.  No collapsing allowed.

Comment: I know that each constant sequence corresponds to its real number. But then what i'm confused about is in the original example what would the actual equivalence class be. I thought it would be the set containing the constant sequences 1,5,8 but i'm clearly wrong.

Comment: Or could you possible given an alternative example to help clarify my understanding at all?

Comment: The equivalence class of a sequence cannot be a *set*.  It has to be a single number (a hyperreal number).  That number could have different values depending on the ultrafilter: either $1$, $5$, or $8$.

Comment: So [K]=1,5, or 8 but we cannot say specifically which one

Comment: You should add the word "or" before $8$.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. So say there was K=<1,9,2,1,9,2,...> [K]=1 or 2 or 9 (assuming Odd numbers are in ultrafilter)

Comment: No you are still confused.  Whether this sequence will represent $1$, $2$ or $9$ has nothing to do with whether the set of odd numbers is contained in the ultrafilter.

Comment: But we then index along each of the odd numbers in K to get the values 1,2,9 respectively... I can see in this example if the even numbers where in the ultrafilter we would get the same answer, but why doesn't it matter what's in the ultrafilter. I'm getting so confused now

Comment: You should try to understand the example of the sequence $(-1)^n$ well first. When does it represent $1$ and when does it represent $-1$?

Comment: it would represent 1 for even n and -1 for odd n. But what would you say its equivalence class is would we literally just write [(-1)^n]= 1 or -1

Comment: Wrong. Which integer it represents depends on whether the set $\{1,3,5,\ldots\}$ is in the ultrafilter or whether its complement is in the ultrafilter. Do you know what an ultrafilter is?

Comment: So it depends on whether the odd numbers are in the ultrafilter. So then why earlier did it not depend on them being in the ultrafilter. Yes I know what an ultrafilter is, and the difference between principal and non-principal

Comment: Not "the odd numbers" but rather "the set of odd numbers".

Comment: Okay I knew that part, just my lack of precision in terminology. But then how would we write what the actual equivalence class is for this sequence. If we say that the set of odd numbers is in our ultrafilter then would we write [(-1)^n]= -1?

Comment: Exactly, modulo the understanding that the real numbers are identified with their image in the hyperreals.

Comment: Got it. And it's similar with things such as addition etc. So let's say that we had K=<3,3,3,3,...> and N=<5,5,5,5...> then K+N=<8,8,8,...> and we would write [K+N]=8? Thanks for all the help btw, I think we were getting confused with terminology each of us were using.

Comment: True.  It doesn't take an ultrafiter to do that :-)

Comment: As a quick aside the halo and galaxy are just cosets right, with the halo being the equivalence class of sequences that are infinitely close to zero and the galaxy being the equivalence class of sequences that are of limited distance apart. However I'm not sure how we can write out a calculation with halos and galaxies other than with hal(0) gal(0) which is just the set of infinitesimal and limited numbers respectively

Comment: No.  If you want to start talking about galaxies and halos, you have to stop talking about sequences.  Sequences were involved in the ultrapower construction of the hyperreals. Once you have constructed them already, you have a number system where you can define halos and galaxies.

Comment: My bad with terminology again. I meant that it is the equivalence class of hyperreals that are infinitely close together (halo). But how would you give concrete examples just do something like if k is an infinitesimal then hal(k)={k+e:e is in hal(0)} i.e. e is an infinitesimal.

Comment: This is true for any $k$. Why do you say that $k$ is infinitesimal?

Comment: Just as an example.

Comment: Anyway I think I understand things a lot better after having been able to discuss them somewhat, and have learnt to be a lot clearer in my communication. Thanks.